# How to produce and consume JSON messages between Django services using Redis as a message queue?

Tags: django, redis, celery, message-queue

I am trying to find a way to enable communication between two **Django** services using **Redis** as a message queue.

One service would produces **JSON** data, publish it to the queue and the other one would consume the message.

Something similar to what I want to achieve is described here using Spring Boot and RabbitMQ: https://www.javainuse.com/spring/spring-boot-rabbitmq-consume

Any articles or suggestions would mean a lot.

Comment: you can use `pickle` instead of `json`.

Comment: @mrash It's not JSON that's the problem, I gave it only as an example. Any format is fine. I need an explanation of the entire publish/consume process using Django.

Comment: I never use Redis but it's an in-memory DB and used for the message queueing. so you can record a text message and use it in another app. But for performance and reprocess string to object it's better to use other formats instead of JSON. You can use manual of redis for getting start in: https://timber.io/blog/background-tasks-in-python-using-task-queues/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. While the article you mentioned is indeed helpful, it's focused on task queues, for asynchronous work. I'm looking for message queue implementation, communicating message data between Django services.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things to you think about:

1. if you want to use redis with django celery (Celery beat).
2. if you want to use just redis as M.Q with django.

Below are the references to help you with each case:

For Case 1: check out the link below

1. https://enlear.academy/hands-on-with-redis-and-django-ed7df9104343

For Case 2: check out the link below

2. [How can I publish a message in Redis channel asynchronously with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63573906/how-can-i-publish-a-message-in-redis-channel-asynchronously-with-python)

(I recommand this one best : https://stackabuse.com/working-with-redis-in-python-with-django/) -- *it covers all you need about using redis for caching*

Comment: Do you think that your post provides an answer, a solution for the question at the top of this page? Other than what is linked? Note that linked content is not considered part of a StackOverflow answer. I think when ignoring the links your post does not contain a solution.